# How to trigger external script after routing in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular2-services

Hi I am new to this angular2. I  have included all external script like fitvids.js,revolution.js etc in index.html and routing is implemented.

First time home page loads everythings works perfectly. After routing i.e if i navigate to some other page and come back to home page. the scripts which is triggered onload,onready etc.

I have seen workaround like manually creating script using ViewChild etc.
By my question if we know specifically what that external plugin does we can write custom script but if people dont know about that or if they have included so many external scripts then what is the solution.?

Can anyone help how to solve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: you need to achieve loading external js scripts dynamically each time when the page loads is this what you need ?.

Comment: I am including all external script before closing body tag. On first time home page loads, script in the external js working perfectly. If i navigate to another page and come back to home page the script is not loading eg: onload script is there in some js those things are not working out since only the view part component is changing not the index.html.

Comment: Yes i want to load dynamically where all page loads. is there something like when home page first loads catch all the events and if next time user comes to the home page trigger all the catched events like that? @MBalajivaishnav